# How to fetch draggable events area from the database in fullCalendar?

Tags: php, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I've been working on developing fullCalendar drag and drop events with a resource column. For now, I've hard coded the draggable events area; now trying to fetch it from the database.
The database previously had two tables - Resources and Events. The events after being dropped on the calendar, gets updated in the events table. The resource column is being fetched from the database and for adding new resources, I've built a rooms button which saves the new resources in the resource table. 
Till now, I only had five draggable events in the main file, but now I'm working on fetching those from database as well. So, I created one more table in the database named draggableevents. The table contains two columns id and EventName.

Here's the code:

draggableevents.php

```
<?php
require "connection.php";
$conn = DB::databaseConnection();
$conn->beginTransaction();
$sql = "Select * FROM DraggableEvents";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
while($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
return $result;
} else {
return null;
}
?>
```

form.php

```
<head>
<link href='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/core@4.4.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/daygrid@4.4.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/timegrid@4.4.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/core@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/interaction@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/daygrid@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/timegrid@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/timeline@4.4.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/resource-timeline@4.4.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
 <script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/timeline@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script>
 <script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/resource-common@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script>
 <script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/resource-timeline@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" media="all">
 <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src='main.js'></script>
</head>
<?php
require 'draggableevents.php';
?>
 <div id='external-events'>
 <p>
   <strong>Draggable Events</strong>
 </p>
  <div class='fc-event'><?php $result['EventName']; ?></div>
  <p>
    <input type='checkbox' id='drop-remove' />
    <label for='drop-remove'>remove after drop</label>
  </p>
</div>
<div id='calendar-container'>
  <div id='calendar'></div>
 </div>
```

The above code results in a blank draggable events area. The draggableevents.php file doesn't seem to be loaded on refreshing the page. I don't see it in the network panel and hence no error related to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some obvious logical issues, none of which have anything much to do with fullCalendar:

1) I have mentioned this a number of times before in your previous questions: `return` does not return a value when you aren't inside a function. Where do you imagine you are returning that *to*, exactly? `require` doesn't have any way to

2) even if that worked, you'd never return any events, because your `while` loop is closed and doesn't do anything.

3) `$result` would be out of scope outside your while loop anyway.

4) You never execute your query

5) You didn't `echo` the event name.

You need to get all your database results into an array, and then loop through that array to generate as many `fc-event` divs as there are entries in the array.

Here's one way to do it - I've put the functionality of draggableevents.php into a function which you can call when you need it.

draggableevents.php

```
<?php
require "connection.php";

function getDraggableEvents() {
  $conn = DB::databaseConnection();
  $sql = "Select * FROM DraggableEvents";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();
  $results = array();
  while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   $results[] = $row;
  }
  return $results;
}
?>
```

form.php

```
<html>
<head>
  <link href='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/core@4.4.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <link href='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/daygrid@4.4.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <link href='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/timegrid@4.4.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/core@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/interaction@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/daygrid@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/timegrid@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
  <link href='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/timeline@4.4.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <link href='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/resource-timeline@4.4.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/timeline@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/resource-common@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/resource-timeline@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" media="all">
  <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src='main.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='external-events'>
    <p>
      <strong>Draggable Events</strong>
    </p>

    <?php
    require 'draggableevents.php';
    $events = getDraggableEvents();
    foreach ($events as $event)
    {
    ?>
      <div class='fc-event'><?php echo $event['EventName']; ?></div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>

    <p>
      <input type='checkbox' id='drop-remove' />
      <label for='drop-remove'>remove after drop</label>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id='calendar-container'>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the explanation. But the above code isn't working either. The resource area is blank and the file doesn't seem to be loaded in the network tab.

Comment: I tried to echo something after each line in form php. When I did that, I got an error saying the $event is undefined.

Comment: "The resource area is blank"...unlikely to be anything to do with this code here. Unless you really mean "the draggable event area is blank"??

Comment: "I tried to echo something after each line in form php. When I did that, I got an error saying the $event is undefined. "....as always, you'd need to show exactly what you did. But let's focus on debugging what's going on here.

Comment: Yeah. Sorry. *the draggable event area is blank

Comment: <?php
    require "draggableevents.php";
    echo 'test1';
    $events = getDraggableEvents();
    echo 'test2';
    foreach ($events as $event)
    echo 'test3';
    {
        echo 'test4';
    ?>
    <div class='fc-event'><?php $event['EventName'] ; ?></div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>

Comment: This is how I tried to debug. So it is echoing test1,test2,test4 and I get an error saying that the $event is undefined on the fc-event line. But I think that's coz I'm trying to echo test3 just after the foreach loop?

Comment: The problem is here. `foreach ($events as $event) echo 'test3';` that echo ends your loop. you need to have it the other side of the `{` so that it occurs during the loop, along with all the other code inside the brackets.

Comment: And it then causes the undefined error, because it means that the code inside the brackets is not considered part of the loop (and so `$event` is then not in scope, because $event only exists within the loop).

Comment: Yeah. No I meant that $event being undefined isn't the actual reason for data not getting printed/loaded in the calendar

Comment: Well it's the reason nothing appears inside the `<div class='fc-event'>`s, if that's what you mean

Comment: If nothing is appearing in your main fullCalendar though, then no, it's very unlikely to be anything to do with this code.

Comment: No. Even when I run the actual code (from your answer), which is without echoing the tests, the draggable events area remains blank, the draggableevents.php doesn't get loaded in the network tab

Comment: "the draggableevents.php doesn't get loaded in the network tab"...you wouldn't expect it to - it's being _required_ by PHP, so it becomes part of your main script. It's not being fetched separately by AJAX.

Comment: So if the draggable area remains blank, I'd guess maybe you don't have any results to display or something, or you got the name of the field wrong. You need to debug it. I can't see what data your query returns, or what's in your database.

Comment: The database has the exact names metioned above. Two columns named id and EventName. The name of the table is DraggableEvents. I've been cross checking it each time I'm making any changes to the code

Comment: Ok I just noticed. You never executed the query! Again, you really should copy/paste from working examples so you don't have this kind of problem. It took me to stare at it a long time and also make a demo, to realise. It's always much easier to realise the mistake when you can actually run some code and debug it properly - I used dumps to trace to the fact that the `while` loop was never executed. Here's a working demo adapted from your original code:  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c7ee85462c8997268da51de89e79c63b1c089ac5 . I've also updated the answer above to give working code.

Comment: Oh and you never `echo` the event name either. I've updated the answer with the extra faults.

Comment: The issue I'm having now is the scrollbar. It only scrolls down the calendar not the draggable events area. Hence the user cannot see the entire list. What should be done to fix that?

Comment: I've no idea. Not enough relevant info to fix that. Ask a separate question if you can't figure it out. Glad what's above helped though